# How to prove the limit of $\frac{r^n}{n^{-5}}$ ($0<r<1$) is 0

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Intuitively, I know it's true. $r^n$ goes to 0 exponentially fast, which should be much faster than $n^{-5}$ when $n$ becomes large.  But I want to prove it. Please help me.

Comment: Maybe it is $\frac{r^n}{n^5}$?

Comment: @CarlosLaguillo It is $\frac{r^n}{n^{-5}}$. Because $0<r<1$, so $r^n$ decreases exponentially.

Comment: "Intuitively, I know it's true." Please explain your intuition.

Comment: Ok, it was just for the way of tipping it, $n^{5}r^{n}$ seems more natural.

Comment: @Did I have added the intuition in the description.

Comment: This is not *intuition* to me... but a good point to start proving things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n = n^5 r^n$. Then

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{(n+1)^5}{n^5}r = r < 1,$$

and hence $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prove that for each $r$ (between 0 and 1) and $\epsilon >  0$, there is an $N$ where your function is smaller than $\epsilon$
(for $n > N$)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint/sketch:**

$$r^n n^5 =  e^{n\log r}\cdot 2^{5\log n} = e^{n\left(\log r + \frac{5\log n}{n} \right)}$$
Now, look at $A_r(n)\stackrel{\rm def}{=}\log r + \frac{5\log n}{n} = -\log \frac{1}{r} + \frac{5\log n}{n}$. Since the second term (non-negative) goes to $0$ when $n\to\infty$ (why?), after a certain $n_0$ it remains smaller than $\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1}{r}$. So for $n\geq n_0$ the whole $A_r(n)$ remains negative, at most $-\frac{1}{2}\log\frac{1}{r}$. Can you tell why this implies $e^{nA_r(n)}$ goes to $0$?